# Localhost points to branch of asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, iis, localhost

I have my Default Web Site setup in IIS with two branches under it
Default Web Site
- Site 1
- Site 2

When I open Site 2 as `localhost/Site2` it redirects to `localhost/randomText/Site2` 
and can obviously not find Site2

The requested URL is shown as `/randomText/Site2`

How can make localhost go to `localhost/Site2`? 
FYI this was working till yesterday suddenly this changed.